How to clip a rectangle on a QR Code with TikZ?
I'd like to clip a rectangle at the center of a QR Code, however it can't satisfy my request.

The first one clips reversed, then I switch the order of node and clip commands, the second one couldn't satisfy the clip effect. How can I achieve the effect?
The MWE is following
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics [width=4em] {example-image.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [draw] (-.5em,-.5em) rectangle (.5em,.5em);
        \node [inner sep=0] at (0,0) {
            \qrcode[height=3em,level=M]{LaTeX}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics [width=4em] {example-image.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}
        \node [inner sep=0] at (0,0) {
            \qrcode[height=3em,level=M]{LaTeX}};
        \clip [draw] (-.5em,-.5em) rectangle (.5em,.5em);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Could you explain, what exactly is the effect that you want to achieve? This is not clear to me.

Same with me. Are you doing artwork, or what’s the purpose? // The clipping doesn’t seem to be that bad … what’s wrong with it?

Actually, I just want to add a logo to the center of a QR code, so I should 'dig' a square hole in the QR code (because I've added watermark to the document, I don't want to draw a rectangle directly at the center of the QR code), then I can put the logo inside the 'hole'.

\clip acts on what follows. If you want to include part of the image in the center of the QR code you should change the order of the instructions in the picture:
%% draw the QR code
\node [inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\qrcode[height=3em,level=M]{LaTeX}};
%% clip
\clip [draw] (-.5em,-.5em) rectangle (.5em,.5em);
%% all following drawings are now clipped, draw the image
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics [width=4em] {example-image.pdf}};

But I'm not sure if the link of the clipped QR code will still work.
Full example:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% draw the QR code
  \node [inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\qrcode[height=3em,level=M]{LaTeX}};
  %% clip
  \clip [draw] (-.5em,-.5em) rectangle (.5em,.5em);
  %% all following drawings are now clipped, draw the image
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics [width=4em] {example-image.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


